# how to find pixel coordinates of an image for plotly scatter plot?

Tags: python, image-processing, plot, plotly

how to find pixel coordinates of an image for plotly scatter plot?

What I am trying to achieve? ::
Scatter plot on top of the metro map with the origin and destination passenger count in animated (hourly basis)

Issue ::
To find the location of each station i have used the "mpld3" to know the pixel location "plt.scatter([365], [824])"  you have to manually find the exact location by adjusting these two values.  But when I use the same values on the ploty scatter plot it's showing a different place.

```
def animate_stations(df, x_col, y_col, animation_frame, size, hover_name, title):

    init_notebook_mode()
    fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x=x_col,
                 y=y_col, 
                 animation_frame= animation_frame, 
                 size= size, 
                 hover_name = hover_name,
                 range_x=(0,2050), 
                 range_y=(2050,0), 
                 width=700, 
                 height=700,
                 labels = {'origin_x':'', 'origin_y':''})
    image_filename = 'metro.jpg'
    plotly_logo = base64.b64encode(open(image_filename, 'rb').read())
    
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, 
                    yaxis_showgrid=False,
                    xaxis_showticklabels=False,
                    yaxis_showticklabels=False,
                    title= title,
                    images= [dict(
                    source='data:image/jog;base64,{}'.format(plotly_logo.decode()),
                    xref="paper", yref="paper",
                    x=0, y=1,
                    sizex=1, sizey=1,
                    xanchor="left",
                    yanchor="top",
                    sizing="stretch",
                    layer="below")])
    iplot(fig)
    
station_coords = {
    'Mall of the Emirates Metro Station':[934, 935]
}    

def get_x_coord(station):
    return station_coords[station][0]

def get_y_coord(station):
    return station_coords[station][1]
```

[image]

To find the pixel in image using the below script (output is not working in the ploty)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import mpld3  
from mpld3 import plugins
img = plt.imread("metro.jpg") 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,14))
ax.imshow(img) 
plt.grid('on')
plt.axis('off') 
plt.scatter([365], [824]) 
plugins.connect(fig, plugins.MousePosition(fontsize=14))
```

[image]

Kindly let me if any have better solution.

Comment: I can't make sense of your post. what is your problem? what do you mean by "location in the plot is not working"? it is not clear what you want to display where and when. give an example input and output. you ask how to find pixel coordinates but you say you already have coordinates. what is your actual problem? read [ask]

Comment: @Piglet Apologies, I have adapted the questions. Find the pixel coordinates in an image for plot scatter plot.

Comment: @Kum_R your question still unclear, you want to find the coordinates of the stations? or you already have the coordinates of the stations, but they become incorrect later because of some modifications on the images, can you explain please, also why do you use `mpld3` library I didn't understand the purpose!

Comment: the question is very unclear but are you trying to find pixel 365,824 on a map with size 700x700?

Comment: @Ruli yes, same like this https://www.kaggle.com/jeffreybraun/animating-bart-rides

Comment: I *think* what you care most about are the actual geographic coordinates.  In that case, you should deal with a package that can handle lattitude and longitude.  For instance, [this](https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/make-scatter-map/) in Plotly or something like [this](https://www.latlong.net/) to get direct latt and long.

Answer (score 2):

In case I understand it correctly here is solution:
1st option: set the size of original image and plot to be the same, or
2nd option: in case you don't want to change the size adjust the coordinates to fit the plot area

```
new_x_coord = int((old_x_coord/old_x_len)*new_x_len)
new_y_coord = int((old_y_coord/old_y_len)*old_y_len)
```

this will move the point to the correct place. Hopefully this will help.